# Batch: Skip folder if it contains a certain string

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch script that moves folders in a directory into another folder in the same directory. However, I want to skip folders that start with "FILES-" (the rest of the folder-name is made up of random characters).

This is what I have so far:

```
echo #### moving folders into newly created folder...
for /D %%D in ("C:\Users\reite\Downloads\*.*") do (
        if /I not "%%~nxD"=="FILES" (
        move "%%~D" "C:\Users\reite\Downloads\%datestamp%"
    )
)
```

How would I go on about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```cmd
echo #### moving folders into newly created folder...
for /D %%D in ("C:\Users\reite\Downloads\*.*") do (
    for /F "delims=- eol=-" %%N in ("_%%~nxD") do (
        if /I not "%%N"=="FILES" (
            move "%%~D" "C:\Users\reite\Downloads\%datestamp%"
        )
    )
)
```

The `for /F` command splits the folder name at `-` characters. The leading `_` is intended to avoid false matches like `--FILES-*` and to not skip folders like `---`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something with findstr/b rather than with for:

```
echo #### moving folders into newly created folder...
for /D %%D in ("%userprofile%\Downloads\*") do (
        echo/%%~nxD|findstr /I /B "FILES-">nul||move "%%~D" "%userprofile%\Downloads\%datestamp%"
)
```

Comment: This could fail if special characters occur in the folder names (e. g., `&`) as they appear unquoted; that's one reason why I tried to avoid pipes; another one is the worse performance due to multiple `cmd` instances...

Comment: Yes, you are right there. I think yours is the better solution.